# Plotting the probability of being assigned to a group

Tags: r, function, math, statistics, curve

There is a meaningful graph [HERE](https://conjointly.com/kb/pre-post-design-relationships/) (scroll down a bit) in this book that shows how the probability of assignment to a group in a study changes for a hypothetical continuous "X" (X-axis) variable.

I was wondering how (*approximately*) this function might be plotted in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called the [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function).

```
f <- \(x, a, b, c) {a/(1 + b*c^-x)}
curve(f(x, a=1, b=1, c=.5), xlim=c(-10, 10), main='Sigmoids', col=4, lwd=2)
curve(exp(x)/(exp(x) + 1), xlim=c(-10, 10), col='orange', lwd=2, add=TRUE)
legend('right', legend=c('foo', 'logistic'), col=c(4, 'orange'), lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: @SimonHarmel It's the [basic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), of course you may define any parameters.

Comment: if the numerator becomes negative the desired result is given(+1).

Comment: @SimonHarmel I confused Sigmoid with logistic, where the ladder is actually a special case of the former. Please see update.